# I need help turning off some setting in Blender

Tags: shaders, lighting

I’m new to blender and accidentally clicked a hot key that turned my normal object into some weird shader mode. I’ve attached an image of what the object looks like. How would I revert my object back to a normal shading mode so it has the default style to it?
Unfortunately I’m not able use ctrl+x to revert my changes as I made multiple other changes before realizing the shading style was changed.

[image: odd shading mode in blender]

Comment: Look to recover the object from an auto-save or blend2 file, and save the file to a new name like "MyFile_Recovered".  Then perhaps you can delete the errant object from "MyFile", and Append the pre-damaged object from "MyFile_Recovered".

Comment: Hi Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that users can at a glance understand what your post is about. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid anything not strictly essential to the post. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and makes your question findable for future users. See ["*What is the problem with posting an image or link and asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: Can you post an image of the complete Blender window please? - You can take a screenshot via Window > Save Screenshot in Blender.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. There must be a hotkey that turned on auto smooth, once I turned it off everything was back to normal.